# Web2py lack of Debug info when using Google AppEngine or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web2py

I've got a "quite simple" python error when I do an HTTP post editing an user I have created.

The error is the following, but at line 115 of editar_usuario.html all I have is a "blank line".
The log below I got from "GAE SDK Log Console"... and that is all I have to work with!

```
File "D:\Dropbox\Devel\www\web2py\gluon\restricted.py", line 212, in restricted
exec ccode in environment
File "D:\Dropbox\Devel\www\web2py\applications\init\views\adm/editar_usuario.html", line 115, in  <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

At the browser, I only have this lines and no ticket is created.

```
Internal error
Ticket issued: unknown
```

Is it usually so difficult to find erros and debug a Web2py app on Google App Engine?

Comment: Tough to say without seeing more of the code, but `D:\Dropbox\Devel\www\web2py\applications\init\views\adm/editar_usuario.html` does not look like a valid file path (`/` before the HTML file). That may be causing an error that returns `None`, after which the object is being called as if it contains content.

Comment: Well... I belive that "/" ocurrs because I'm using Windows... I let the whole path to show that the error is inside a "view" and I don't know why Web2py can't show the right line.

Comment: You can always run dev_appserver in eclipse and debug it.

Comment: dragonx, is it a part of the GAE? When I use the log visualization, is it already dev_appserver?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it usually so difficult to find erros and debug a Web2py app on
>   Google App Engine?

Compared to what?  I had a horrible experience with the Google App Engine and Web2py, mainly because I was using the App Engine, which has a terrible pricing plan and was difficult to pinpoint whether problems were coming from them or the Web2py framework.

The limited access to my data was especially annoying.  I switched to a shared hosting plan with Webfaction where I was given complete control, but unfortunately found Web2py was memory intensive when compared to Django.  I switched my website to Django from Web2py and although I love the guy's at Web2py; Massimo, Bruno, Jonathan etc... Django is the better framework with better support.

Not only are you trying to debug what may be wrong with Web2py, it may be nothing to do with them and everything to do with some sort of App Engine update causing conflicts or just a general bug.  If I haven't already made my point I think the Google App Engine is a horrible idea for anybody trying to get their project off the ground.  I would never go back to them...ever.